# Linking SDL project in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, sdl

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
      start in crt1.10.6.o
     (maybe you meant: _SDL_main)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

This is what I get in Eclipse. Tried to link with -lSDLmain, have SDL.h and SDL_image.h files included, used main with arguments - `int main(int argc, char ** argv)`, but it does not want to link. Please, help.

Answer (score 0):

I found [that link](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/general/21848/) where people try to link the same thing as you. It might help you, in their case the solution was [there](http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/devcpp/index.php).